# What is normal timing advance as seen from my ECU via OBD2?

Tags: ford, timing, fiesta

I am looking for help with my timing advance. I have just got the Torque app and am reading the data from my Ford Fiesta WS Petrol 1.6L 2010 model. [This is the graph](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g1ug05wrq1616q9/Screenshot_20181015-183730_Realtime%20Charts.jpg?dl=0) here. As you can see, RPM is constant (along with a number of other variables) but the timing advance is jumping up and down. Is this normal behaviour?

[image]

Edited:

I was driving yesterday with cruise control and watching the engine timing advance, and it is dropping 15 degrees almost instantly then going back to the value it was. I feel a gentle jerk when this happens. This is the image of this log while it was happening. Is this normal?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm not entirely positive, but would bet this is normal behavior. Since all of this is 1:1 and the graph is sitting in the 7-10° advance, that really isn't a lot of variation. The computer could be easily directing this to happen and I wouldn't think twice about it. There are others on here who are more expert than I on reading this stuff, so I'll leave them to answer.

Comment: This is normal.  You can take a look at a couple other Ford 1.6l at https://www.pidfusion.net/datalogs/Ford/

Comment: Looking at Ford 1.6l on pidfusion.net/datalogs/Ford does not show any logs for a Ford Fiesta at idle. All logs are with the accelerator being pressed down, then released, then repeated.

Comment: @John - When on pidfusion.net, keep an eye on the range of each graph. 
Although it appears the accelerator is pressed repeatedly, the range is only less than 1%, and I would blame that on slight voltage fluctuation.  The "Complete line Graph" page toward the bottom also has a graph of the PIDs in question.  There the legend is interactive so you can select what to mute out and also a box zoom tool. You should be able to see that the throttle was not pressed repeatedly at the beginning of the log.  Since you have Torque pro, why not upload a log of your own and then post a link to it?